# Managing ssh keys

Tags: ssh, gitlab, forwarding

Suppose that I have a remote server and GitLab private repository.

I do not want to add key from my server to ssh keys in GitLab account, so I make ssh key forwarding.

However, when I try to run my initial installation scripts with `sudo`, I cannot pull the repository because with sudo my ssh keys are not accessible on the server.

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Check first, as [in here](https://serverfault.com/a/448972/783), if you can allow the other user (`sudo -u otheruser`) to access `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` file, and it's directory.

That way, you would still benefit from the original SSH tunnel: simply [giving more permission to `$(dirname $SSH_AUTH_SOCK)`](https://serverfault.com/a/1040239/783) can be enough.